# ¿Cómo puedo establecer el alto de un <div> que se encuentra dentro de otro <div>

Tags: css3

Quisiera saber si es posible mediante `css` establecer el alto de un  interno tomando en cuenta el valor del alto del  padre ya que realice aparte varios media queries (tamaño de pantalla de celular, y tamaño de pantalla de tablet) y en ellos voy a darle estilo a una etiqueta p, precisamente modificar el `font-size`

Lo que tengo en el html es:

```
<div class="contador-icono">
   <i class="icon-basket"></i>
   <div class="box-cont">
      <p id="cont">0</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
No establecí una altura específica al contenedor padre pero el contenedor que lo contiene tiene un  ``line-height: 2.125em`` el cual cambia su valor para la visualización en celular.

Lo que deseo alcanzar es que la ``<div class="box-cont">`` sea un círculo pequeño que se ubique en la parte superior derecha y que el <p> sea de 0.6250em. Ya cambie el font size y también ya le dí un border-radius. Aún me falta que el <p> este en el centro del círculo (que se centre en el eje x como en el eje y).
en el css tengo:
```

.contador-icono {
display: flex;
position: relative;
}
.contador-icono .box-cont {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 14px;
padding: 2px;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index: 100;
}
#cont {
font-size: 0.6250em;
}

```
Estoy leyendo sobre ``calc()`` porque creo que me va a servir aunque sea para un futuro y que la posible solución lo va a utilizar.
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber entendido lo que precisas, y creo que estás rebuscando mucho con muchas propiedades dificiles de manejar cuando lo colocas con más elementos. Te muestro lo que hice:
Primero reorganicé el html

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle">
      <p class="number">5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Definí un contenedor que encierra el circulo y el numero. Un contenedor que simulará ser el circulo, y un párrafo que contiene un numero

```
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <p class="number">5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y luego le dí estilos:

```
html,
  body {
    /* Ajustes generales básicos */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .circle {
    /* Hago que la disposicion de los elementos sea de manera central */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    /* Le doy un ancho y alto iguales, */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    /* Le doy un fondo, un espacio interno y le doy la forma de circulo */
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
```